# Why does скучать mean both "to be bored" and "to miss"

Tags: выбор-слова

I was writing a letter to a friend where I said "скучаю тебя" (to mean "I miss you"). But then I remembered that "скучать" means "to be bored" and I panicked because I thought I misremembered the verb for "to miss" and was telling my friend that I think they are boring/that they make me bored (when of course the opposite is true).

However, apparently it [means both](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C). Is there ever any danger of ambiguity or sever misunderstandings when using the word "скучать"?

I am kind of afraid to use "скучать" now and would prefer to find alternatives to "скучаю тебя", since I don't want to insult people who are close to me.

Comment: Я *без* тебя скучаю.--еще один вариант.

Comment: You should be afraid of using "скучаю тебя" not because of "скучать" also means "to be bored" but because "скучаю тебя" is wrong :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Believe it or not, for most of my life, I (a native speaker) wasn't aware they were the same word, until one day it just hit me. The thing is, **мне скучно** is a *massively* more common way to say "I'm bored" than **я скучаю**, so the latter pretty much defaults to "I miss" unless the opposite is very clear from the context. (And, as already pointed out, it's **я скучаю по тебе**, not *тебя*. The "bored" one uses **от** as its natural preposition.)

P.S. To answer the question in the title–*why* does it mean both "to be bored" and "to miss": they're two different extensions of the same, now-lost original meaning, which is to howl or whimper.

Comment: I am a native speaker - and never heard phrase _я скучаю от тебя_

Comment: @AleksG that's because `мне скучно от тебя` is so much more common. And I bet you have heard something like `скучать от однообразия`.

Comment: @AleksG  well, like "скучно от этой всей суеты"

Comment: @shabunc _скучать от чего-то_ - yes; _скучать от кого-то_ - no... although I can see why/how it could be used.

Comment: @AleksG I'd rather agree

Comment: @AleksG Quite possibly. The reason I brought up `от` in the first place was to point out another reason why you can't (or can super-rarely) get the two meanings mixed up.

Comment: and `скучаю` in the sense of `being bored` usually appears alone without any complement, `скучно` has one more frequently but still pretty rarely

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov by `to howl or whimper` you mean `скавчать`? interesting that Ukrainian has both forms `скучати` and `скавчати` with different meanings of course

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I didn't know that. I was thinking of the Czech `skučet`, and Wiktionary tells me Serbian `скучати` means more or less the same.

Comment: Чё делаешь? Скучаю. Почему? Закончил смотреть всю сантабарбару, а больше ничего хорошего посмотреть и нету. - и в этой ситуации нет ни грамма кокетста, человеку просто скучно и нечем заняться, и не смотря на очевидную вымышленность ситуации, я бы не удивился что человеку скучно. От интонации же зависит и пола.

Answer (score 6):

Because

> Я скучаю по тебе - I miss you

actually means:

> Мне скучно без тебя - I'm bored without you

Comment: However, «скучать без дела» (to do nothing) is not the same as «скучать по делу» (to miss a meaningful work)

Comment: but very close..

Answer (score 5):

First, correct usage is *скучаю по тебе*.

Now, you are correct, word *скучать* can mean both, however the main difference is in usage.  If you want to indicate that you missing something/someone, you would indicate what/who you are missing.  If you keep only the verb without adding any subject(s), then it would mean that you're bored:

Compare:

> Я скучаю **по тебе**
>   I miss **you**
>
> Я скучаю **по дому**
>   I miss **home**

with

> Я скучаю
>   I am bored

Comment: То ли городовой в медалях заметил, что странный человек усмехнулся, когда ему указал на ворону извозчик, то ли городовой *скучал от безделья*, но он покинул свой пост у губернаторского подъезда, перебежал к памятнику и, махая руками, принялся шугать ворону: [С. Т. Григорьев. Иегудиил Хламида